# Why doesn't my profile on a new site show my name?

Tags: support, bug, user-accounts, display-names

I am an active user of Stack Overflow and several other Stack Exchange sites. Today I wanted to leave a comment on a [question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/25955) at matheducators.stackexchange.com, so I clicked through to make a linked account based on my Stack Overflow account.

To my surprise, the comment appears as posted by "user20820", not as by "Karl Knechtel". Why? I cannot recall it having done this on any other Stack Exchange sites when I did the same thing. The corresponding user profile seems to be aware of my network profile - it's showing me my other accounts, all of which in turn display my name, which I didn't have to set individually.

Comment: It's also using a different identicon. Can you just rename yourself manually? You could go to the edit page for your Stack Overflow profile and copy that one to all the other network sites.

Comment: I would prefer not to try to work around the problem until I have a proper understanding of it.

Comment: Also interesting: it seems that the user ID I was assigned, is lower than others that were already in use.

Comment: Sure it´s "user20820" and not "user21820"?

Comment: @convert yes; I copied and pasted it to ask the question here. Someone with a similar (but, curiously, *higher*) numeric ID dropped in after me.

Comment: There's nothing unusual about anyone's user ID. There is, however, someone who joined the site slightly before you who chose to name themselves after their Stack Overflow user ID (which is significantly higher than their actual ID on Math Ed). The real ID is always the one in the URL. (See [list of new users](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate))

Comment: Hmm. I'm going to suggest that "alarabmarketing", "Buy Trustpilot Reviews" and "Mapledrivingschool" might not be bona fide new users with a genuine interest in math education. "Spammer" could be ironic, though.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I would agree, but as long as they don't post anything it's not worth the time spent to go about to delete them.

Comment: Also your math educators account shows up in your network profile, so it is indeed connected. You could contact a CM by going through the Contact button at the bottom of the page, or try as @Laurel proposed.

Comment: I guess you changed email over the years, and the system used your new email when you created the account on that new site. This explains the different avatar, but not sure why it didn't take your existing display name. Probably only staff can give actual reply.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel users with "Spammer" as their username are accounts that have been reset by a moderator somewhere around the network. Moderators have userscripts that do these resets and push the changes network wide. For obvious reasons a site moderator can't nuke users across the network. (but they do destroy such users on their own site).